# Error al actualizar sequelize 4.40 en mi proyecto

Tags: nodejs, promesas, sequelize.js

Estoy desarrollando una plataforma en la cual actualicé sequelize a la versión 4.40 y me indica el siguiente error.

> error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>       at Function._validateIncludedElement (C:\Users\Zrismart23\Documents\GitHub\gestion-nuevo\sip\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:535:42)
>       at options.include.options.include.map.include (C:\Users\Zrismart23\Documents\GitHub\gestion-nuevo\sip\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:395:37)
>       at Array.map ()
>       at Function._validateIncludedElements (C:\Users\Zrismart23\Documents\GitHub\gestion-nuevo\sip\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:390:39)
>       at Promise.try.then.then (C:\Users\Zrismart23\Documents\GitHub\gestion-nuevo\sip\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1570:14)
>   From previous event:
>       at Function.findAll (C:\Users\Zrismart23\Documents\GitHub\gestion-nuevo\sip\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1566:8)
>       at Function.findOne (C:\Users\Zrismart23\Documents\GitHub\gestion-nuevo\sip\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1752:17)
>       at C:\Users\Zrismart23\Documents\GitHub\gestion-nuevo\sip\routes\sistema.js:43:50
>   From previous event:
>       at req.session.save (C:\Users\Zrismart23\Documents\GitHub\gestion-nuevo\sip\routes\sistema.js:41:28)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)

El código de la ruta es es siguiente:

```
menu.builUserdMenu(req, function (err, data) {
            if (data) {
                req.session.save(() => {
                    req.session.passport.sidebar = data
                    models.pagina.belongsTo(models.sistema, {
                        foreignKey: 'idsistema'
                    });
                    models.pagina.belongsTo(models.contenido, {
                        foreignKey: 'idcontenido'
                    });

                    return models.sistema.findOne({
                        where: {
                            id: idsistema
                        }
                    }).then(function (home) {

                        return models.pagina.findOne({
                            where: {
                                nombre: home.pagina
                            },
                            include: [{
                                    model: models.sistema
                                },
                                {
                                    model: models.contenido
                                }
                            ]
                        }).then(function (pagina) {
                            var tmpl = pug.renderFile(pagina.contenido.plantilla, {
                                title: pagina.title
                            });
                            var script = ""
                            if (pagina.script)
                                script = pug.render(pagina.script);

                            return res.render(home.pagina, {
                                user: req.user,
                                data: data,
                                page: home.pagina,
                                title: pagina.title,
                                type: pagina.contenido.nombre,
                                idtype: pagina.contenido.id,
                                html: tmpl,
                                script: script
                            });
                        }).catch(function (err) {
                            logger.error(err);
                        });

                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        logger.error(err);
                    });
                })
            } else {
                res.render('index', {
                    message: err
                });
            }
        });
```

Estaría agradecido si me pudieran ayudar, ya que he estado una semana completa intentando solucionar mi problema.

Comment: Hi.. this is the spanish version of SO.. please translate your question.

Comment: Es que formulé la pregunta en las dos versiones y acá lo copié. Mi error está en la actualización de sequelize donde mi modelo no sufre cambios, pero la ruta reclama que sobre una asociación llamada 'name' de models de sequelize que no hace referencia a esa.

Comment: Aca las preguntas van en español. Si no, va a ser cerrada.

Comment: ahí si?, ahora espero su ayuda para poder solucionar mi problemática.